# limits' definition

Tags: category-theory

Please, can somebody help me? I was given the following definition of the LIMIT:
Let $I$ be a small category and $F:I \to C$ a covariant functor ( where $C$ is a category), $K \in Ob(C)$, $\sigma:k_{K}\to F$, where $k_{K}$ is a constant functor such that that diagram commutes. I dont understand that: that functor $k_{K}$ is defined on the $I$ category to $C$ and $k_{K}(i)=K$?, for every object $i \in I$? Did I understand correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Chances are this $k$ is a diagonal functor; but your definition seems very incomplete. Wanna put up a source, reference, or a more complete definition.

Comment: This is the definiton from my course..I dont have another one. Can you explain why it is incomplete? My teacher gave me this definition.

Comment: see @Oskar's answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $k_K(i)=K$ and $k_K(f)=id(K)$ for every $i\in Ob(I)$ and every $f\in Arr(I)$. It is called a *constant functor* and usually is denoted by $\Delta_K\colon I\to C$. The functor $\Delta\colon C\to C^I$ (which
Musa Al-hassy mentioned in comment), such that $\Delta(c)=\Delta_c$, is called a *diagonal functor*.

The object $K\in Ob(C)$ is a limit of the functor $F\colon I\to C$ iff there exists a natural transformation $\sigma\colon \Delta_K\to F$ such that for any object $K'\in Ob(C)$ and any natural transformation $\sigma'\colon \Delta_{K'}\to F$ there exist a unique arrow $f\colon K'\to K$, such that for every object $i\in I$ the equality $\sigma(i)\circ f=\sigma'(i)$ holds.

Comment: See edit: I've corrected the terminology in the first paragraph.